# Querying AngularFire2

Tags: firebase, angular

No encuentro una documentación sobre como hacer una consulta en este caso usando **ref.where()** y **orderBy()**
Si el return lo hago utlizando el where() no tengo problema, pero cuando quiero ordernar los resultados de forma 'desc' no devuelve nada.
Estoy utilizando:

> Angular: 6.1.6
>
> "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.12",

```
this.figurasCollection = this.afs.collection<any>('figuras', ref => {
  const query = ref.where('year_torneo', '==', '2019_apertura')
            .where('division', '==', 'a_fds') ;
  query.orderBy('goles', 'desc');
  return query;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

segun tu codigo deberia de funcionar, de todas maneras prueba con esto:

```
    this.figurasCollection = this.afs.collection<any>('figuras', ref => {
        return ref.where('year_torneo', '==', '2019_apertura')
                  .where('division', '==', 'a_fds')
                  .orderBy('goles', 'desc');
      });
```

con respecto a la documentación para las Query : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?hl=es-419